# Basic writing to a CSV file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i was looking for help writing to a csv file in python 3. I have the code below but it only seems to write to the first line, whenever i run the code again it overwrites the first line.

```
import csv

with open("scores1.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["score", "username","topic","difficulty",]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    score = int(input("score" ))
    user = input("user: ")
    topic = input("topic: ")
    difficulty = input("difficulty: ")

    writer.writerow({"score": score, "username": user, "topic": topic, "difficulty": difficulty})

print ()

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: what does: `writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)` do ? maybe it should be something like: `for line in csvfile: writer = csv.DictWriter(line, fieldnames=fieldnames)...` ?

Answer (score 1):

`writerow()`, unsurprisingly writes a single row. So it needs to be enclosed in a `for` loop iterating over each record to be written to the file.

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: As you are collecting input from the user rather than reading from a file you might want to investigate Python's "while" loop.